# Masking the stop function in R

Tags: r, error-handling

Is there a way to override the built in error handler `stop`? I would like for `stop` to always print the call stack when it is called, rather than having to use `traceback` afterwards. One reason for this is that using `source` causes the traceback to be meaningless, as the traceback will always be the same 4 calls when using `source`, regardless of what the error was in inside.

Comment: see `?options`, search for "error" ...

Comment: +1, in particular, `options(error=recover)` is a very common one.